# VB - How can I grab input from textboxes in a loop?

Tags: vb.net

Currently I am working on a project where the user enters 6 names and then 5 numbers per name into text boxes. The program is meant to insert each name and its associated numbers into an array of structures as well as an average of those numbers, which is also displayed on the form. I really do not want to have to initialize 36 variables directly, so I went about searching for ways to cycle through the text boxes in a loop. After some searching, I found it was suggested to some people that I use something like this to access the controls:

```
Me.Controls("txtTextBoxName" & variable)
```

Using this idea, I created this code to handle my process:

```
Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dblTempAvg As Double

    Try
        For intCount = 0 To 5
            dblTempAvg = 0
            ClassScores(intCount).strName = Me.Controls("txtStudent" & (intCount + 1)).Text
            For i = 1 To 5
                ClassScores(intCount).dblTestAvg = CDbl(Me.Controls("txtStudent" & (intCount + 1) & "Test" & i).Text)
                dblTempAvg = dblTempAvg + ClassScores(intCount).dblTestAvg
            Next
            dblTempAvg = dblTempAvg / 5
            Me.Controls("lblAvg" & (intCount - 1)).Text = dblTempAvg.ToString("p")
            ClassScores(intCount).dblTestAvg = dblTempAvg
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Please enter all names and test scores")
    End Try
```

The problem is when I attempt to debug this the program is stopped at the first Me.Controls statement by a System.NullReference exception. I'm honestly stuck at this point, can anybody help me figure out where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend setting a breakpoint at that first Me.Controls.  Then when it breaks leverage the Watch Window to inspect what exists and go from there.

Comment: That error message means that you don't have a control with that name on that parent. Make sure that you're using the correct name and the correct parent, e.g. if you added the `TextBox` to a `Panel` then you need the `Controls` collection of that `Panel` rather than of the form.

Comment: Or your ClassScores array contains null/Nothing at position intCount.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the suggestion of jmcihinney (I'm sorry I can't figure out how to respond to comments). I neglected to mention that all of my controls were in a group box, I replaced the Me with the name of my groupbox and the program worked perfectly

Comment: Event if you don't have enough reps to post comments generally, you can always post comments on your own questions. To respond to a particular commentors post start with @ then the first letter of the commentors name. A little box will pop up above your comment and you can select it and it will be inserted into your comment. Then continue your comment. The person will receive the comment in his inbox.